# Is python-omniorb package available for Ubuntu22

Tags: python, python3

I am upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 and need a package python-omniorb which I use under Ubuntu 20.04 but cannot find it for Ubuntu22.  I have used the package search but it finds only  Ubuntu20.  Is it available some where or replaced by something.  Is contains python bindings for omniORB.

Answer (score 1):

`python-omniorb` was the package for python2.7, which has been deprecated since 2020.

The python3 version of omniorb is not yet available on the software repositories. However, you can use pip3 to install [it](https://pypi.org/project/omniorb/).

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --user omniorb
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried pip3 install --user omniorb and omniORB and python-omniorb but all said no matching distribution found .

Comment: all the download files on pypi look like they are for "win"

Comment: I am still looking for this and I still see nothing on pip3 or search on pypi.  Is there a python3 interface to omniORB equivalent to python-omniorb that was for python2.7